# how can i access main variables in public void stock() function?

Tags: java, function, class

In method `void stock()`, how can I access variables like `int c;` and `quan[c];` and `objIn[c];` from method `main();`

Please tell me how can I access to variables that declared in `main` method in other methods?

```
package inventry;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Inventry {

public void Stock()
{


    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
  System.out.println("-------STOCK AVAILABLE---------");
  System.out.println("-------------------------------");

    for( int c=0;c<objIn.length;c++)
   {
      System.out.println(objIn[c]+"="+quan[c]);
   }

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("_____________________________");
     System.out.println("WELCOME TO INVENTRY SYSTEM");
    System.out.println("_____________________________");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER NO OF OBJECTS FOR INVENTRY=");
    Scanner Inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,j,c;

   i=Inp.nextInt();

   Inp.nextLine();

   String objIn[]= new String[i];
   String quan[]= new String[i];


  System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER NAMES OF OBJECTS");
   for(j=0;j<objIn.length;j++)
   {
     System.out.println("OBJECT NO."+j+"=");
       objIn[j]=Inp.nextLine();
   }


  System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER QUANTITY OF OBJECTS");
   for(j=0;j<objIn.length;j++)
   {
     System.out.print(objIn[j]+"=");
       quan[j]=Inp.nextLine();
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code by four (04) spaces to make it appear as code.

Comment: supply them as arguments of declare globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables that are needed to be accessed by stock() can be sent via a parameter list, and the method stock() can then be called inside main(), where these variables can be provided as arguments. However, please be aware that your stock() method is not static, hence you will need to create object of Inventry class. If you are not instantiating Inventry class, then you should declare stock() as static.

Stock() should be declared as:

```
public static void Stock(int i, String objIn[], String quan[]){ ... }
```

and should be called inside main() as:

```
Stock(I, objIn, quan);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please explain me what means "not static" and "instantiating"?

Comment: This requires a basic read of OOP concepts. non-static properties are properties of an object that are related to individual objects, instead of the class. i.e. every object will have its own copy of the property. e.g. for a Student class, student's name is an instance property, since every object of the class (i.e. every student) should have a name of his/her own. Similary, properties like student's ID, student's GPA etc. are all instance properties, as opposed to minimum credits required for graduation (which in case of most undergraduate programs in US is 120). Common properties are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this variables to method `Stock()` but for that you need to change signature of this method to `public void Stock(int i, String quan[], String objIn[])`.

And then when you call method `Stock` from `main` method you may pass your variables to `Stock` like this `Stock(i, objIn, quan)`, but only after you declare this variables.

Because your method `Stock` not `static` you need to create instance of class `Inventry` and invoke this method, for example:

```
Inventry invObject = new Inventry();
invObject.Stock(i, objIn, quan);
```

Comment: to pass values and using this function in main()   Stock(c,quan[],objIn[]);  is this the right way??

Comment: @TSjahangiri. Yes because when you need access to variable in another method you need to pass this variable to another method and only change method declaration give you this opportunity.

Comment: Please explain what means not static?

Comment: @TSjahangiri. Static means that variable(field) or method of the class not belong to the instance of the class. And you can invoke this methods and use variables without creating instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create an array list of objects(items in stock), each object will be a stock item and will have a quantity. That way you wont need to create parallel arrays as each item in your single array will be a stock item with a quantity field.

```
public class Stock(){
    private String stockItem;
    private int quantity;

    public Stock(String itemNm, int intemQuant){
      this.stockItem = itemNm;
      this.quantity = itemQuant;
    }

    //insert relevant getters and setters.
```

BACK IN MAIN:

```
Arraylist<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<Stock>(numberOfItems);
for(int i = 0; stockList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(stockList.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println(stockList.get(i).getQuantity());
}
```